# How to filter out data on the basis of employee id and project id

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of objects which is having individual task and I need to filter out the each task according to employee id and then project id and after this I need to check if the sum of hours in the resulting array is less than 4. If all these conditions satisfy then store those values in the array. This is the response from api.

```
nonallocated: [
  {
    empId: "1",
    task: {
      project: {
        projectId: "111"
      },
      total: '2'
    }
  },
  {
    empId: "2",
    task: {
      project: {
        projectId: "111"
      },
      total: '5'
    }
  },
{
    empId: "2",
    task: {
      project: {
        projectId: "333"
      },
      total: '1'
    }
  },
  {
    empId: "3",
    task: {
      project: {
        projectId: "111"
      },
      total: '2'
    }
  },
  {
    empId: "3",
    task: {
      project: {
        projectId: "111"
      },
      total: '1'
    }
  },
  {
    empId: "1",
    task: {
      project: {
        projectId: "222"
      },
      total: '5'
    }
  },
  {
    empId: "1",
    task: {
      project: {
        projectId: "111"
      },
      total: '1'
    }
  }
]
```

Expected output:

```
newArr = [
  //matching empId(1), projectId(111), total is less than 4 i.e 2+1=3
  {
   empId: "1",
   task: {
    project: {
      projectId: "111"
   },
   total: '2'
  }
 },
{
   empId: "1",
   task: {
    project: {
      projectId: "111"
   },
   total: '1'
  }
 },
// having only one data for same empID and projectId and total is less than 4
{
  empId: "2",
  task: {
    project: {
      projectId: "333"
    },
    total: '1'
  }
 },
//having same empId(3) and projectId(111) and total is less than 4 ie 
  2+1 =3
{
empId: "3",
task: {
  project: {
    projectId: "111"
  },
  total: '2'
}
},
{
  empId: "3",
  task: {
    project: {
      projectId: "111"
    },
    total: '1'
   }
  },
 ]
```

this should not be limited to one empId or projectId. I want these conditions to satisfy on any data for example we can have a data which has same conditions satisfied for empId 2. I want to retrieve the data for values which have same employee Id, same projectId and total less than 4. and if I have a data which doesn't have empId and projectId matched with other data just check the total less than 4 in that case.

Create a separate array for same employee id and same project id.

Comment: array.filter((e) => e.empId === value) ?

Comment: What is value in this?
We want to filter it dynamically

Comment: This reads like the requirements for a coding exercise. Can you rephrase the question with context on what your code does so far and where you're having issues?

Answer (score 0):

I had a hard time understanding what you wanted but I think that's it. You'd still have to sort in order to get the exact output that you wanted but in term of filtering that's okay (If I got it right):

```js
const nonallocated = [
  {
    empId: "1",
    task: {
      project: {
        projectId: "111",
      },
      total: "2",
    },
  },
  {
    empId: "2",
    task: {
      project: {
        projectId: "111",
      },
      total: "5",
    },
  },
  {
    empId: "2",
    task: {
      project: {
        projectId: "333",
      },
      total: "1",
    },
  },
  {
    empId: "3",
    task: {
      project: {
        projectId: "111",
      },
      total: "2",
    },
  },
  {
    empId: "3",
    task: {
      project: {
        projectId: "111",
      },
      total: "1",
    },
  },
  {
    empId: "1",
    task: {
      project: {
        projectId: "222",
      },
      total: "5",
    },
  },
  {
    empId: "1",
    task: {
      project: {
        projectId: "111",
      },
      total: "1",
    },
  },
];

const totals = [];
const threshold = 4;

// initial filter

// then we calculate the totals for each pair of empId projectId
nonallocated.forEach((element) => {
  const index = totals.findIndex(
    (e) =>
      e.empId === element.empId &&
      e.projectId === element.task.project.projectId
  );
  if (index === -1) {
    // we add it to our totals
    totals.push({
      empId: element.empId,
      projectId: element.task.project.projectId,
      total: +element.task.total,
    });
  } else {
    // we increment it
    totals[index].total += +element.task.total;
  }
});

// then we filter when total is < 4
const filteredTotals = totals.filter((e) => e.total < threshold);

// finally we filter our inital array
const newArr = nonallocated.filter((e) =>
  filteredTotals.find(
    (f) => f.empId === e.empId && f.projectId === e.task.project.projectId
  )
);

console.log(newArr);
```